# Is it worth changing my blog URL structure for better SEO, or could that cause a ranking loss?

Tags: seo, url, blog

My blog URL structure is like below:

```
www.example.com/blog/postkeyword

www.example.com/blog/category/category-name/subcategory-name
```

Example:

```
www.example.com/blog/category/marketing/seo
```

Does it need to change? Or is it good? 
I am afraid that if I change the structure my site could go backward in ranking.

Comment: URLS are for users not search engines.

Comment: If a post can be in multiple categories you'll also want to ensure you have a canonical meta tag to reduce duplicate pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth keeping clean, structured URL. If Content is same and you're doing proper Redirect after changing the structure, it won't affect your rank most of the time.

Structured website is better for the User + Bot as well it helps both of them to understand website more easier.

**Let's take an example.**

The web site owner is writing articles about "What is the concept of email marketing?" and putting articles under "/blog/category/marketing/e-mail-marketing/" where sub category is too deep.

They can do something "/blog/marketing/e-mail-marketing/" to avoid deep linking URL and make it more clear. I would suggest to make change "/blog/category-name/sub-category-name/"

Possible URL Structure suggestion for your site is as below

```
www.example.com/blog/what-is-the-concept-of-email-marketing - Blog Post URL

www.example.com/blog/marketing/e-mail-marketing/ - Category URL
```

[image]

More Info:

https://moz.com/learn/seo/url

https://moz.com/blog/15-seo-best-practices-for-structuring-urls